# Azure Peering Hub and Spoke Overlapping IP ranges possible?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I would like to setup Azure [Hub-Spoke architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=cli) with VNET Peering leveraging "transitive capability" with a VPN Gateway (or an Azure Firewall or other network virtual appliance) in the Hub network forwarding traffic between the spokes. I understand that in directly connected VNET-to-VNET peering's the IP ranges **cannot** overlap each other. However, when there is an Hub in the "middle" **can** the spokes' IP overlap? I mean, is the use of the Hub "void" the IP overlap constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

In Hub and Spoke model architecture in Azure, **we cannot have spoke VNETs with overlapping IP addresses**

**The Spoke VNETs with overlapping IP addresses cannot be peered to the Hub VNET**

The Hub cannot void the IP overlap constraint